# Проблема со шрифтом icofont

Tags: linux, шрифты

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) icofont.woff2
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) icofont.woff

Кто может подсказать в чем проблема, путь до шрифтов указан верно, но все равно ошибка не найдено 404

Comment: 404 - ты через вебсервер пытаешься это всё открыть? Чё логи говорят? А с разрешениями на файлы всё ок?

Comment: @don Rumata Localhost, да все окей, например fontaweson работает без проблем.
icofont не работает не могу понять в чем проблема, хотя все пути корректные.